# What does Runtime error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute '<field_name>' mean?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop

Here is my code

```
#arcpy
import arcpy,sys

from arcpy import env

env=r"C:\Users\Jaya\Desktop\python_practice"
totalRec=arcpy.GetCount_management("river")

rows=arcpy.SearchCursor("river")
row=rows.next()

pp=[]

for row in rows:
    initialH=row.RASTERVALU
    for r in range(1,55):
        val=val+1
        headav=initialH-row.RASTERVALU
        if(headav>=50):
            if(r>=12):
                break
        elif(headav<50):
            if(r>=12):
                row=rows.next()

        row=rows.next()
    print headav
    pp.append((row.POINT_X,row.POINT_Y_1,headav))
    row=rows.next()


pt=arcpy.Point()
ptGeoms=[]

for p in pp:
    pt.X=p[0]
    pt.Y=p[1]
    pt.Z=p[2]
    ptGeoms.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(pt))

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeoms,r"C:\Users\Jaya\Desktop\python_practice\power_plant.shp")
```

I am getting error message like this:
*Runtime error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'RASTERVALU'*

Can you help me in this regards

Comment: Your question is very vague.  Can you tell us more what you are trying to do, and maybe what line in your code is erroring?

Comment: "RASTERVALU" looks like a typo for "RASTERVALUE" or something like that.

Comment: What is the data type of layer "river"?  If it does not have attributes then that could explain the error.

Comment: River is a shape file

Comment: I have river network shape file in river layer. I need to  check for the criteria of head difference between the starting point and consecutive point. Minimum head difference should be 50m and Minimum distance between two points should be 1080. In my case distance between two consecutive points is 90m. So i have given minimum count as 12

Comment: and maximum distance between two points is 5000m

Comment: Jaya please update your orginal question with your comments - the question is rather vague.

Answer (score 4):

As you are using a `for` loop to iterate through the rows there is no need to use `row=rows.next()` see [online help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Cursor/018z0000009r000000/) for an example.  Inside the `if` statement you can simply use `continue` to ignore the rest of the `for` loop and move to the next row.

The `break` statement, breaks out of the smallest enclosing for or while loop.

The `continue` statement, continues with the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: I have tried removing row=rows.next(), it is not working it it giving the same result as input file

Comment: Did you remove all 4 cases where you were using it.  The error message you get suggests that in the line `headav=initialH-row.RASTERVALU` you attempt to access the RASTERVALU property on the row variable but row is equal to `None` which is equivalent to null in Python.  This may mean you have moved row beyond the end of the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

If the "river" feature class is a shapefile, you need the ".shp" added when you reference it.  Try changing the following line:

```
rows=arcpy.SearchCursor("river.shp")
```